# Does not recognize usb sticks and drives

Tags: 10.10, usb, thinkpad

When connecting any usb stick to my thinkpad ubuntu 10.10 does not recognize them. I don't see anything on the desktop.

the output of "dmesg | tail -n10" gives me:

```
[ 1965.696388] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1965.884537] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1966.072503] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1966.260349] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1966.506227] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
[ 1966.572375] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1966.760379] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1966.948358] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1967.136335] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 1967.325423] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
```

When connecting my usb scanner to the same port:

```
[ 2008.480135] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 65
[ 2008.548389] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2008.736786] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2008.924379] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2009.112348] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2009.300443] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2009.488536] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2009.732180] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 71
[ 2014.796299] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 2018.000128] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
```

And ubuntu 10.10 recognizes that scanner. So What can i do to see my usb stick? On my other Thinkpad running fedora 14 it works perfectly...

It happens only to storage media (usb sticks, cameras, etc.). My scanner (HP scanjet 2200c) works like a charm.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` with your USB device plugged in.

Comment: Platte /dev/sda: 60.0 GByte, 60011642880 Byte
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 7296 Zylinder
Einheiten = Zylinder von 16065 × 512 = 8225280 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004c9de

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        6993    56165376   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            6993        7296     2437121    5  Erweiterte
/dev/sda5            6993        7296     2437120   82  Linux Swap / Solaris

Comment: @Peter Please add the new information to your question, not a comment, thanks!

Comment: I don't see the relevance of this information to the question...

Comment: Does this only happen with one USB port, or all of them?  Is the Thinkpad running Fedora identical, hardware-wise?  Can you try Ubuntu 10.10 on the other Thinkpad (perhaps via livecd), to see if the problem occurs there?  Do you have any other USB devices attached?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It happens only to storage media (usb sticks, cameras, etc.). My scanner (HP scanjet 2200c) works like a charme. I'll try to use a livecd on my other ThinkPad and i will post the results here. BTW: All the hints mentioned here did not work. it's a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if any of these ideas will help you, but here I go....
Some options to check (I'd start on points 3 and 5):

2. Check this question, too: [USB Storage Device Automount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3872/usb-storage-device-automount), and try the solutions proposed there.
3. Also, you can try `palimpsest` to check if it's detected and then mount it.
4. In 10.04 (some people reported it with 10.10, too) there seemed to be a bug that prevented usb automounting. Don't know if that's fixed, but you can try the solution for that case (note that it disables floppy support): `sudo modprobe -r floppy` ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/fix-usb-devices-automount-not-working.html))
5. Yet another possibility (quoting [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1485070)):

   > I eventually solved this problem by
   >   uninstalling pmount, then
   >   re-installing together with
   >   libpmount0.0
   >
   > Now drives are detected, automount and can be safely removed. No idea what caused the problem on the upgrade, but hope that this helps other people with the same problem.
6. [Here](http://www.atareao.es/ubuntu/conociendo-ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid-lynx-y-usb/) you can find another workaround:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/modules
   ```

   Add two lines (at the end of file):

   ```
   usb_storage 
   usbhid
   ```

   (Actually you can check with `modprobe -l |grep usbhid` and `modprobe -l | grep usb_storage` if those moduled are already loaded or not before doing the edit.)

Comment: Ooops that link http://www.atareao.es/ubuntu/conociendo-ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid-lynx-y-usb/ is not really english...

Comment: Sorry... but indeed I took my time to write the solution which is suggested there... in English... for you all... specially you, the asker ;). Anyway, if you need me to translate anything from there for you, just ask... I will be glad to....  and for free :). On the other hand... did any of my suggestions help?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a couple times lately and it always turns out to be a USB hub or port (hardware) problem. Have you tried different ports and bypassing any hubs?

Answer (score 0):

Check your groups. I've had similar problems due to not being in the `floppy` group.

To see what groups you're in, run:

```
groups
```

If you're not in the `floppy` group, you can add yourself to it by running:

```
sudo usermod -a -G floppy $USER
```

Comment: @StephenMyall, I disagree. My suggestion wasn't about improving the question but about eliminating one possible cause of the problem.