# Mounting thumb drive

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, usb-drive

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition. I have some data on a thumb drive that I want to put on my computer but when I plug in the thumb drive, nothing happens. I search for the file and it's not there. /media is empty. How do I mount this thumbrive and make it mount automatically?

output of dmesg. The Total output was too large, so I put in what I thought would be relevant:

```
[ 2043.086937] wlan0: associated
[ 2523.345076] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[ 2523.647942] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[ 2523.648585] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 2523.649787] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 2523.649796] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[ 2524.660116] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 2524.665393] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2525.902179] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4028416 512-byte logical blocks: (2.06 GB/1.92 GiB)
[ 2525.902776] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2525.902787] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 2525.902795] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2525.906549] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2525.906570]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2525.910640] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2525.910656] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2638.233056] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, address 3
[ 2643.460114] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[ 2643.598968] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 2644.596900] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 2644.599789] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2644.819235] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 4028416 512-byte logical blocks: (2.06 GB/1.92 GiB)
[ 2644.819872] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2644.819884] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 2644.819892] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2644.825499] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2644.825533]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2644.834616] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2644.834632] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2925.444581] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, address 4
[ 3090.808101] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[ 3090.945921] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 3091.944884] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 3091.946451] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 3093.224574] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4028416 512-byte logical blocks: (2.06 GB/1.92 GiB)
[ 3093.225499] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3093.225517] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 3093.225527] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3093.229707] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3093.229762]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3093.232970] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3093.232993] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3134.507536] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, address 5
[ 3139.169115] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[ 3139.308938] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 3140.308945] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 3140.310423] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 3140.550352] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 4028416 512-byte logical blocks: (2.06 GB/1.92 GiB)
[ 3140.551040] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3140.551059] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 3140.551072] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3140.557789] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3140.557821]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3140.564267] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3140.564279] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4639.380928] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, address 6
[ 4749.180094] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7
[ 4749.319077] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 4750.316850] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 4750.319861] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 4752.278001] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 4028416 512-byte logical blocks: (2.06 GB/1.92 GiB)
[ 4752.278603] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4752.278616] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 4752.278626] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4752.283289] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4752.283320]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4752.289263] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4752.289286] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: See the output of dmesg after inserting the drive.

Answer (score 2):

The thumbdrive should mount automatically. If not, it is quite possible the filesystem is corrupted.
Indeed, see the output of `dmesg` (find the `Log File Viewer` in `System»Administration`) and observe any messages that appear as soon as you plug in the thumbdrive.

If the thumbdrive's filesystem is indeed corrupted, there is a process to extract your files, at least some of them.

**Update:** Try to mount the USB stick manually.

1. Open a terminal window
2. Run `mkdir /tmp/mountpoint`
3. Run `mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp/mountpont`

Observe any errors.

If there is no error from the last command, then look into /tmp/mountpoint/ your files should be in there. At this point we can try to figure out why automount does not work.

Comment: thumbdrive's filesystem isn't corrupted. (I've reformatted the thumbdrive a couple times trying to get this to work using FAT and ext4).

I can't find system>>administration because this is the netbook edition.

Comment: Great, thanks. I tried that, and got my files off the usb drive. Any ideas about how to find out what's going on with automount?

Comment: Please check next answer and tell us if it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Some options to check (I'd start on points 3 and 5):

2. Check this question, too: [USB Storage Device Automount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3872/usb-storage-device-automount), and try the solutions proposed there.
3. Also, you can try `palimpsest` to mount it (update: you already mounted it, so no need to do this)
4. In 10.04 (some people reported it with 10.10, too) there seemed to be a bug that prevented usb automounting. Don't know if that's fixed, but you can try the solution for that case (note that it disables floppy support): `sudo modprobe -r floppy` ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/fix-usb-devices-automount-not-working.html))
5. Yet another possibility (quoting [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1485070)):

   > I eventually solved this problem by
   >   uninstalling pmount, then
   >   re-installing together with
   >   libpmount0.0
   >
   > Now drives are detected, automount and can be safely removed. No idea what caused the problem on the upgrade, but hope that this helps other people with the same problem.
6. [Here](http://www.atareao.es/ubuntu/conociendo-ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid-lynx-y-usb/) you can find another workaround:

   `sudo gedit /etc/modules`

   Add two lines (at the end of file):

   `usb_storage`

   `usbhid`

(Actually you can check with `modprobe -l |grep usbhid` and `modprobe -l |grep usb_storage`if those moduled are already loaded or not before doing the edit)