# Is it possible to partition an USB drive from command line without root access?

Tags: partitioning, gnome, usb, mount, usb-drive

This is a follow-up question from [Mounting USB mass storage devices without root access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208236/mounting-usb-mass-storage-devices-without-root-access) where I asked about mounting USB partitions **without root access** and **without installing new packages** in Ubuntu. This was after an observation that, by opening the "disks" utility manager in Ubuntu, root access is not required to mount USB thumb drive partitions whereas the "mount" command in terminal needs root access. The solution was using "udisksctl" to mount the USB thumb drive without root access.

The issue is that with this command I am only able to mount the drive, not to partition it. There may be a way by interacting with the "disksd" daemon as stated in the "disks" documentation but I was not able to achieve it.

I discovered then by reading the documentation and looking on the internet that in truth, what I called Ubuntu disks utility manager is in fact opened by the "gnome-disks" command. Hence I was looking for a way of using "gnome-diks" in the terminal to do the things I could to with the GUI. I haven't found a way of using "gnome-disks" in command line.

As I am able in the GUI of "gnome-disks" (standard Ubuntu disk manager I believe) to mount and partition USB drives (without root access), I have then the following question,

**How to do what's done from the GUI "gnome-disks" from the command line (with the same permissions i.e. non-root access, without installing new packages)?**

**If it's not possible is there any other way of partitioning USB drives without root access or any additional package, from the command line ?**

I may have missed the GUI "gnome-disks" utility asking for password but for this case (mounting/partitioning USB mass storage devices) I believe it doesn't. I also may have missed something easy to do this with but the others standard way of partitioning disks always (as far as I can tell) ask for root access (parted, fdisk, cfdisk, ...).

Comment: If `gnome-disks` does not ask for an admin password before beginning a partitioning operation, then that's a bug and a big security hole. Please verify and --if needed-- file the appropriate bug report.

Comment: I can verify that Disks alias `gnome-disks` can edit the partition table as well as create file systems, at least in a USB pendrive. I think we can discuss if it is a security risk somewhere else because this original poster wants to use this feature, actually to extend it to the command line.

Comment: I can confirm that, straight after reboot, while logged in with a user in the sudoers file (able to execute sudo command), I am able to partition a USB thumb drive (mass storage device) with the GUI gnome-disks without any password asked to elevate the user's privilege.  It doesn't seem to me like a bug in the utility, as I feel like any user has to be able to partition its USB thumb drive without requiring root access, but I am no expert. If someone can confirm "gnome-disks" is not supposed to behave that way feel free to create a bug report.